# Reactjs load time with parallel processing

Tags: reactjs, parallel-processing

We are developing a solution with ReactJS, based on excel for calculating certain values and show them in the grid cell which is having rows and columns. Each cell is having certain formula which may depend on other cell(s) for calculating its value.

```
E.g.   Cell A = Cell D + Cell Q, 
       Cell D = Cell P + Cell K
```

So on and so forth.

As the number of cells are increasing the loading time of the grid is increased exponentially. I am trying to find some ways I can reduce the load time by running things in parallel.
Example: first x set of cells can run on one thread and other x set can run on other thread and then I can ties this together.

Or if there is any other way I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Running such algorithm in browser will strongly limit your options. My initial guess would be to run tasks in a pool of [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to avoid blocking the main thread and not to freeze the UI.

For technical implementation, I would recommand to look at this tutorial: [An Introduction to Using Web Workers in React](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/introduction-to-web-workers-with-react/) from 2018.

## Basic exemple :

### worker.js

```
export default () => {
    self.addEventListener('message', e => {
        if (!e) return;
        let result;
        // Run your algorithm
        postMessage(result);
    })
}
```

### React component

```
import worker from './worker.js';

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.worker = new WebWorker(worker);
};

onClickAction = () => {
        this.worker.postMessage('Perform actions');
        this.worker.addEventListener('message', event => {
            this.setState({
                results: event.data.results
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.